# SSIS Row Count For All Files Within a Folder

Tags: ssis, rowcount, foreach-loop-container

I have a folder which contains multiple Excel files that are replaced daily. I need a total row count that gives me the sum of row counts from each individual Excel file within the folder (i.e. if there are 3 files with 10 records each, I need a result count of 30). I then need to run this package daily to add an individual record to a log table that will provide me with the daily count of records in the folder. I've been trying Foreach Loop Containers and ADO Enumerators but cannot seem to achieve a solution.

Comment: You can do it with a script task that uses interop to look in the Excel files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TabAlleman. I'm new to Script Tasks and have not used interop before. Could you elaborate on how to use this or point me to a helpful resource?

Comment: No unfortunately I don't have anything handy.   Best I can do is give you those keywords to google.

Comment: Hi, Alex.  In addition to @TabAlleman's input, I'd also recommend using Bing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good solution that you can apply without the need to use any script task. All you need to use is a "Foreach loop container" , a "Data Flow Task" and a "Execute SQL task"

Define Variables:

- V_FilesPath-> (String) Will hold the path where your files are located
- V_FileName-> (String) will be populated with the files name in the Foreach Container
- V_RowCount (Int)
- V_FileRowCount (int)
- V_TotalRecords (int)

Define the Foreach:

[image: Package Mock up]

[image: Foreach Definition]

Map your Source file to a RowCount Component and select the Variable: **V_FileRowCount**
[image: Source Definition]

In the **"Execute SQL task"** change the result set to **"Single Row"**
[image: SQL Task Definition]

Map the ResultSet to the following variables: 
[image]

In the **Expression** part of the **"Execute SQL task"** Choose the following Property Expression: 
[image]

In the Expression Pane issue the following:

> " SELECT " + (DT_STR,10,1252)@[User::V_TotalRecords] + " + "   + (DT_STR,10,1252)  @[User::V_FileRowCount] + ", 1 + " +(DT_STR,10,1252) @[User::V_RowCount]

Once you've completed the aforementioned you're done!

If you wish to see the result add a Script task (Just to display the results)

[image: Script task definition]

and paste the following Script Code **instead of** the part that starts with **"Public Void Main"**

```
        public void Main()
{

    try
    {

        string Variables = "Loop Counter: " + Dts.Variables["User::V_RowCount"].Value.ToString() + "                       Total Records in all files: " + Dts.Variables["User::V_TotalRecords"].Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(Variables).ToString();

    }



    catch (Exception Ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Row Count** component.

Create a Data Flow Task in the Control Flow. Then, inside Data Flow, use an Excel Source component connected to a Row Count component. Create an integer variable, double click the Row Count component and assign the variable to it.

If you configured your Excel Source correctly (with an Excel Connection Manager), the variable you created will hold the number of rows in the Excel file you're passing.

[image]